# ruby roo TypeError: Book1.xlsx is not an Excel file

Tags: ruby, excel

I have a simple Excel spreadsheet in `.xlsx` format and want to use `roo` to parse it.  I get the following error.

```
Roo::Excel.new("Book1.xlsx")
# => use Roo::Excel.new to handle .xls spreadsheet files. This has .xlsx
# TypeError: Book1.xlsx is not an Excel file
```

It reads OK if I first convert the Excel file to `.xls` format, but I want to avoid that step as I have to do this many times. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
Roo::Excelx.new("Book1.xlsx")
```

Refer to the [github](https://github.com/Empact/roo) page for other usage information